# Inspect browser using Amazon Device Farm or something similar

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, testing, android-webview

I have a website that has a bug that I've only been able to replicate in Samsung S3 default browser. I've been able to replicate the bug using Amazon Device Farm. My problem is though I can't figure out how to inspect the webpack when using the default browser on the Samsung S3 that is provided via Amazon Device Farm.

How can I actually debug this thing, to see some console outputs and figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

It is good to know that you are using the remote access feature for replicating the bug. Device farm does not alter any behavior of the device so if you can see the bug in the remote device you should be able to see it locally.

**How to debug?**

The output of your remote session with the device will be available in the form of logcat and the video of your session after you end your session. These can be found under "Files" tab for your run.

Currently, accessing the remote device for live debugging is not available.

Hope the above pointers answer your question.